# TST10 entered my command twice

Tags: batch-file

I'm following an online tutorial here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vv9j1pDkZvM to learn how to reboot my modem automatically using telnet and tst10. But I'm having problem with it when logging into my account.

I have 3 files. RebootBatch.bat, try.txt and TST10.exe

The code in RebootBatch.bat is like this:

```
cd c:/tst
tst10.exe /r:try.txt
```

Code in try.txt is like this

```
192.168.1.1
WAIT "Login:"
SEND "tmadmin\m"
WAIT "Password:"
SEND "tmadmin\m"
WAIT "->"
SEND "13\m"
WAIT "==>"
SEND "1\m"
```

But when I execute Reboot.bat it goes like this

```
BCM96338 ADSL Router
Login: tmadmin
tmadmin
Password: tmadmin
```

and wouldn't proceed.

I think it supposed to go like this

```
BCM96338 ADSL Router
Login: tmadmin
Password: tmadmin
```

So basically it insert the username "tmadmin" twice in the new line.
How can I fix this?
Since I'm not a programmer myself so please be more detailed on what I should do to fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that's your problem; tst10.exe double-echoes everything for me as well, but it still logs in OK. When it "wouldn't proceed", what does it say in the status bar at the bottom? "Current State: ... {something}"

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Yeah it says "current state: waiting for: ->" which is what is I typed in the try.txt. Since it double input my username so I think that's what makes it incorrect and doesn't login successfully. But when I do it manually it works ok and didn't input my username twice

Comment: why are you using "mypassword~" in the vbs for your password, when you used "tmadmin" as your password in try.txt? I wonder if you missed something in your password - perhaps `\m` off the end in the real try.txt - oh well, well done finding a working solution anyway.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler oh yeah you're right. Thanks for pointing out. I  placed the original code here and forgot I actually edited mine. I will change it to the code that I had edited earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I found another solution to my problem.

I just execute the following code as vbs file and my modem will restart.

```
Option explicit
Dim oShell
set oShell= Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "telnet"
WScript.Sleep 3000
oShell.Sendkeys "open 192.168.1.1~"
WScript.Sleep 3000
oShell.Sendkeys "tmadmin~"
WScript.Sleep 3000
oShell.Sendkeys "tmadmin~"
WScript.Sleep 3000
oShell.Sendkeys "13~"
WScript.Sleep 3000
oShell.Sendkeys "1~"
Wscript.Quit
```